# Partially tinting sprite with pixel shader

Tags: colors, xna, sprite, hlsl, pixel-shader

I can't tint my sprite with color shader. Here is the problem:

[image]

Image on the left is from XNA, and right one is form gimp. Colored sprite still have some blue pixels. Blue color is used to pass tint. I think scalling or anti-aliasing mess it up. Here is my code:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{      
    float4 color = tex2D(s0, coords);      
    float3 white = {1, 1, 1};
    float3 colorTint = { 0.3f, 0, 0 };
    if(color.a)
    {
        if(color.r < 0.1 && color.g < 0.1 && color.b > 0.1)
        {
            color.rgb = lerp(white, colorTint.rgb, 1 - color.b);
            color.a = 1;
        }
    }
    return color;  
}
```

Edit:
Looks like setting sampler state to "SamplerState.PointClamp" is my solution, but maybe someone can tell me what's going on here?

Comment: could be that didn't cover all shades of blue? try passing shader on non-scaled sprite and compare to original.

Comment: @Davor Looks like unscalled image is ok. What i should do now? I thought that pixel shader will save me from creating second texture.

Comment: yes... it should. it looks that shader didn't pass some shade of blue.  i cant test now, but try playing with this function. maybe `color.b > 0` instead of `color.b > 0.1`... it looks it's still there some blue shade that is not affected by shader.

Comment: That's not issue, for instance this code:
`if(color.r < 0.1 && color.g < 0.1 && color.b != 0)`
gives extract same result:
http://s13.postimg.org/yw92gswdf/example.png

Comment: That's not issue (in my image there is blue above 120, that's nearly 0.5), for instance this code:

`if(color.r < 0.1 && color.g < 0.1 && color.b != 0)`

gives extract same result:

http://s13.postimg.org/yw92gswdf/example.png
(scaled image on left side, not scaled (in xna) on right side)

I am sure that scaling mess up my shader (becasue it mix blue with other pixels and add green and blue). I don't know how this works, but probably scaling is done before shader pass.


I use this code to scale sprite:
`spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteSheet, Position, Dst, Src, Color, Rotation, Origin, Scale, Se, 0);`